# function getting a delegate from pouchDB, insert some debug data and return a promise

Tags: angular, sqlite, typescript, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I pretend to intercept functions from pouchDB and send it to a log API. After that I will return a promise to any part who needs to use.

I Created a Function accepting a Delegate and a param of any type. But is return me a error message:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '_closed' of undefined
    TypeError: Cannot read property '_closed' of undefined
        at vendor.js:172457
        at vendor.js:81588
        at vendor.js:172415
        at new t (polyfills.js:3)
        at vendor.js:172402
        at vendor.js:81588
        at main.js:54
        at new t (polyfills.js:3)
        at LogSystemProvider.webpackJsonp.111.LogSystemProvider.interceptAndDebug (main.js:52)
        at DbService.webpackJsonp.43.DbService.bulkDocs (main.js:6141)
```

Function:

```
public interceptAndDebug(func: DelegateDTO): Promise<any>;
  public interceptAndDebug(func: DelegateDTO, param: any): Promise<any>;
  public interceptAndDebug(func: DelegateDTO, param?: any): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(param){
        func( param )
          .then((res)=>{

            let msg: ValueDebug = {
              nameFunc: func.name,
              param: param,
              sucess: res
            }

            this.CreateLog({
              msg: JSON.stringify(msg),
              isDebugger: true
            });

            resolve(res);
          })
          .catch((err)=>{

            let msg: ValueDebug = {
              nameFunc: func.name,
              param: param,
              error: err
            }

            this.CreateLog({
              msg: JSON.stringify(msg),
              isDebugger: true
            });

            reject(err)
          });
      }else{
        func()
          .then((res)=>{

            let msg: ValueDebug = {
              nameFunc: func.name,
              param: param,
              sucess: res
            }

            this.CreateLog({
              msg: JSON.stringify(msg),
              isDebugger: true
            });

            resolve(res);
          })
          .catch((err)=>{

            let msg: ValueDebug = {
              nameFunc: func.name,
              param: param,
              error: err
            }

            this.CreateLog({
              msg: JSON.stringify(msg),
              isDebugger: true
            });

            reject(err)
          });
      }


    });
  }
```

DelegateDTO:

```
export interface DelegateDTO {
  (any?): Promise<any>;
}
```

Use of Function:

```
bulkDocs( list: Array<any> ){
    return this._logSystem.interceptAndDebug(this._db.bulkDocs, list);
}
```

Is there somebody who could help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `bulkDocs` is a method of `this._db`, you probably need to bind it so it does not lose the context of `this._db`:

```
return this._logSystem.interceptAndDebug(this._db.bulkDocs.bind(this._db), list);
```